# Generated toString() text from class name

Tags: java, regex, tostring

I am devicing an abstract class that will override toString() with an automated message, as such:

```
public abstract class AbstractTask {

    abstract void run();
    abstract int calculate();

    private String makeMessage() {
        String raw = this.getClass().toString();
        // do regex stuff here!
    }  

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return makeMessage();
}
```

My implemented (extends AbstractTask) classes might be called something like

```
TaskXRQMinimize
TaskListParallell
TaskVerifyRepositoryEmpty
TaskCreateXRQs
TaskCreateZRQs
TaskSendAllSRQToTLS
```

The output I want to have when calling the classes toString() methods are:

```
Task XRQ Minimize
Task List Parallell
Task Verify Repository Empty
Task Create XRQs
Task Create ZRQs
Task Send All SRQ To TLS
```

I made a simple regex pattern to find these words:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+|[A-Z]{3}[a-z]?)
```

How do I implement this?

Comment: do u want to find XRQ, SRQ and TLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `toString()` abstract as well, force subclasses to implement it by returning fixed string. Throw away parsing class name and using regular expressions - too fragile and with poor performance. If you *really* want to make it this way, at least do the computations once per class, not every time `toString()` is called.

As for the regular expression, I have something better: [StringUtils#splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) (there is really no need to reinvent some things):

```
StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase("fooBar")     = ["foo", "Bar"]
StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase("foo200Bar")  = ["foo", "200", "Bar"]
StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase("ASFRules")   = ["ASF", "Rules"]
```

In your case:

```
//yields [Task, Send, All, SRQ, To, TLS]
StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase("TaskSendAllSRQToTLS")
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use something like `str.replaceAll("(\\w)([A-Z]\\w)", "$1 $2")`

I have not tried this but it looks reasonable. It replaces all sequence like aBc to "a Bc".

Comment: Cool! Seem to work ok with some tweeks, can you explain what "$1 $2" do?

Answer (score 1):

this should put you on the right track:

Parts of the regex that you want to extract, surround with (). then

```
    String raw = "TaskXRQMinimize";
    String regexp = "([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)([A-Z]{3})[a-z]?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("AFSDgaf " + matcher.groupCount());
        System.out.println("afdgafd " +  matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("afdgafd " +  matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just iterate on the name of the class and build a new String. the rule is pretty simple: if the current char is upper case and the next is lower case, then you sould insert a space before the current.

Comment: You'r forgetting about the abveriations, such as SRQ and TLS! Especially the plural ones, i.e. XRQs.

Comment: It works with abrevations, except plural ones. I didn't noticed that, sorry. Anyway, I agree with Tomasz, this is not a good practice.

Comment: You're right that regex might be bad practice for such a simple problem.